# Check if IPhone is connected to WiFi when locked

Tags: python, iphone, linux, ubuntu, ping

I try to check if my IPhone is connected to my network. Therefore, I wrote a small python script as follow:

```
...
response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + iPhone-name)
if (response == 0):
    print "is available"
else:
    print "is not available"
...
```

The script works somehow. If my iPhone is unlocked and connected to my network, I get "is available" and vice verca. The problem is, that I would like to know if my iPhone is connected, regardless of whether it is unlocked or not. In addition, the script doesn't work if I try the ping with the IP address. Unfortunately, my router doesn't have an API and isn't able to trigger events if a device is connected or not.

---

**Solution I found:**

```
def pingdevice(ip):
ping = subprocess.Popen(
    ["ping", "-c", "1", ip],
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr = subprocess.PIPE
)

out, error = ping.communicate()
# print(out)
text = 'host unreachable'

#Bulb NOT reachable
if text in str(out):
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Comment: Is it possible that your phone enters low-power mode when screen is locked and does not respond to pings? I don't have an Iphone to check.

Comment: See here for example: https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/27v37a/wifi_turns_off_when_locked_how_do_notifications/

Comment: Try `lsof |grep ESTABLISHED |grep DNS`

Comment: Solved with subprocess.Popen(). See in my post